# Changing height of div if list LI has UL using jquery not working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a Horizontal menu which works fine for me but as per design requirement i need to change the height of `<div id="nav-subMenu"></div>` if main/parent menu `li` doesn't have any `ul` or submenus in other words. jquery which i wrote is not working for me i would appreciate help in this regard.

Here is an example of [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zMty8/)

`if ($('#nav-wrapper ul li').has('ul'))` always return `true`

**Sample jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    if ($('#nav-wrapper ul li').hasClass('active')) { //if it does have the class active
        if ($('#nav-wrapper ul li').has('ul')) {
            alert('aaaa');
            $('#nav-subMenu').css("height", "30");
        }
    }
});
```

Sample HTML code

```
<div id="nav-wrapper">
   <ul class="dropdown dropdown-linear" id="nav">
      <li><span class="dir"><a href="#">Home</a></span></li>
      <li><span class="dir"><a href="#">About Us</a></span></li>
      <li><span class="dir"><a href="Articles.aspx?PageID=5&amp;Language=en-us&amp;ParID=0&amp;Issue=5&amp;CID=1">Articles</a></span></li>
      <li class="active">
         <span class="dir"><a href="Page.aspx?PageID=6&amp;Language=en-us&amp;ParID=0&amp;Issue=5&amp;CID=1">Categories</a></span>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="Page.aspx?PageID=6&amp;Language=1&amp;ParID=6&amp;Issue=1&amp;CID=18">Book Review</a></li>
            <li><a href="Page.aspx?PageID=6&amp;Language=1&amp;ParID=6&amp;Issue=1&amp;CID=16">Business</a></li>
            <li><a href="Page.aspx?PageID=6&amp;Language=1&amp;ParID=6&amp;Issue=1&amp;CID=3">Culture</a></li>
            <li><a href="Page.aspx?PageID=6&amp;Language=1&amp;ParID=6&amp;Issue=1&amp;CID=2">Economy</a></li>
            <li><a href="Page.aspx?PageID=6&amp;Language=1&amp;ParID=6&amp;Issue=1&amp;CID=19">Finance</a></li>
            <li><a href="Page.aspx?PageID=6&amp;Language=1&amp;ParID=6&amp;Issue=1&amp;CID=17">Infrastructure</a></li>
            <li><a href="Page.aspx?PageID=6&amp;Language=1&amp;ParID=6&amp;Issue=1&amp;CID=20">Lifestyle</a></li>
            <li><a href="Page.aspx?PageID=6&amp;Language=1&amp;ParID=6&amp;Issue=1&amp;CID=21">Others</a></li>
            <li><a href="Page.aspx?PageID=6&amp;Language=1&amp;ParID=6&amp;Issue=1&amp;CID=7">People</a></li>
            <li><a href="Page.aspx?PageID=6&amp;Language=1&amp;ParID=6&amp;Issue=1&amp;CID=1">Politics</a></li>
            <li><a href="Page.aspx?PageID=6&amp;Language=1&amp;ParID=6&amp;Issue=1&amp;CID=4">Sports</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span class="dir"><a href="News.aspx?PageID=3&amp;Language=en-us&amp;ParID=0&amp;Issue=5&amp;CID=1">News</a></span></li>
      <li>
         <span class="dir"><a href="Page.aspx?PageID=12&amp;Language=en-us&amp;ParID=0&amp;Issue=5&amp;CID=1">Archive</a></span>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="Page.aspx?PageID=1&amp;Language=1&amp;ParID=12&amp;Issue=1&amp;CID=1">106</a></li>
            <li><a href="Page.aspx?PageID=3&amp;Language=1&amp;ParID=12&amp;Issue=3&amp;CID=1">102</a></li>
            <li><a href="Page.aspx?PageID=4&amp;Language=1&amp;ParID=12&amp;Issue=4&amp;CID=1">103</a></li>
            <li><a href="Page.aspx?PageID=5&amp;Language=1&amp;ParID=12&amp;Issue=5&amp;CID=1">109</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
         <span class="dir"><a href="Multimedia.aspx?PageID=10&amp;Language=en-us&amp;ParID=0&amp;Issue=5&amp;CID=1">Multimedia</a></span>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="Videos.aspx?PageID=11&amp;Language=1&amp;ParID=10&amp;Issue=1&amp;CID=1">Video</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
 <div id="nav-subMenu"></div>
<div id="NewsTicker"> </div>
```

UPDATE: Firebug view to get idea when jquery should fire to add height to DIV
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your problem and this is working as you desired, try this out:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  if ($("#nav-wrapper li.active").length) {
    alert('yes there are .active class');
    if ($(".active").has('ul').length) {
      alert('yes .active class has ul');
      $('#nav-subMenu').css("height", "60px");
    } else {
      alert("NO .active class don't have ul");
      $('#nav-subMenu').css("height", "0px");
    }
  } else {
    alert("NO .active class found.");
  }
});
```

check this out in the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zMty8/27/

Comment: It always return true; I am not sure if something is wrong with the HTML code it self to me it looks fine.

Comment: yes your code just loops through all the li and one of it has the class `active` then it will apply the css code of jQuery.

Comment: It still show the submenu on mouse hover even if it is empty or doent have any submenu or ul element.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker Try this new updated answer works as per your screenshot.

Comment: beside this i want this to happen on page load event not only on mouse over event..

Comment: I still dont understand why did not it work `$('#nav-wrapper ul li').has('ul'))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 if ($('#nav-wrapper ul li').has('ul')) {
     $('#nav-subMenu').css("height", "30px");
 }
 if ($('#nav-wrapper ul li').has('ul')) {
     alert('a');
     $('#nav-subMenu').css("height", "30px");
 }
```

Reference [here](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

Comment: It trigger the condition for both irrespective of ul or li is present or not

Comment: In your jquery above try this: `$('#nav-wrapper .active').has('ul')` in your if statement, then set the height.

Comment: even this doesn't not work, i am not sure where thing are going wrong logically your code should work.

Comment: I think what you want to do is hide the submenu if the `li` doesn't have a `ul`?

Comment: Yes hide submenu, I think you got it right. but on the other side it should also add heigh to nav-Submenu div

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    if ($('#nav-wrapper ul li').hasClass('active')) { //if it doesn't have the class active
        if ($('#nav-wrapper ul li > ul'.length > 0)) {
           $('#nav-subMenu').css("height", "30");
        }
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/zMty8/2/)**

Comment: I had tried same code before but it didn't work, It adds the height in either case while i need to add height only if `li'` or `ul` is present inside the main(parent menu) `li`.

Comment: It should not add height to `nav-submenu` div for Home About Us but to Category menu as it has submenu.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker I think no one is getting your question. I think this code works only when parent `li` has `ul` inside it.

Comment: Then why are you calling the code on `ready` event. I think it must be on `click` event of menu items.

Comment: @Arvid, Logically your code looks fine to be but it doesnt work as required. What i want is that It should add height `#nav-subMenu` this `div` only if it has submenus. I am trying to trap this scenario by checking if my parent menu has any submenu `li` or `ul` element present. May be i am wrong but this is teh basic logic i am looking for

Comment: I just dont understand when do you want to perform this check, on page load, on click or anything else.